# IIS pool stops on first request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have .net framework 4.8 web site deployed on IIS 10. And It's pool stops on every first request after each start.
Here is the list of programs and features on server:
[Programs and features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPWG7.png)

In Application Windows log I found 10 errors per each request. Everyone error is:

> The Module DLL C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\aspnetcore.dll failed to
> load.  The data is the error.

And in System log I have warning:

> A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '2968' serving application pool '{MyPoolName}' reported a listener channel failure.  The data field contains the error number.

With binary data in details tab: In Words 0000: 8007007E

I tried to repair installed version of .net 5. Also tried to install .net framework 4.8, but installer didn't allow to do it because of:

> .NET Framework 4.8 or a later update is already installed on this
> computer.

I even tried to create site with empty directory. When I create one on my computer it shows "403.14 — Forbidden" as it should. But after doing the same on server empty site pool stops as my site's pool.

Have you ever faced such a problem? I have no idea how to fix it!

Comment: Install VC++ runtime please, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0

Comment: What is your project? your problem tag is asp.net mvc, but the error message is aspnetcore.dll failed to load. you can try to remove the applicationhost.config file and try again.

Comment: Lex Li, thanx, but VC++ Runtime has already installed on server. Nevertheless I updated it and nothing changed.

Comment: samwu, Yes, my site is made on .net mvc, not on .net core. But error in Windows Application log is about aspnetcore.dll. That's really strange for me. Also becasue I have no applicationhost.config inside site folder. Do you mean other location?

Comment: @Sergei In this path: `%SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I solve the problem with complete reinstallation of server OS and components. My consider is that the problem was into iis or OS component.

Answer (score 1):

I have .net framework 4.8 web site deployed on IIS 10. And my IIS pool stopped on first request. Researching similair issues I found this artcle on the *Microsoft Monitoring Agent APM* service. This service was disabled, I removed the *Microsoft Monitoring Agent APM* as it was not being used. My application now successfully launches.

https://kevingreeneitblog.blogspot.com/2017/03/scom-2016-agent-crashing-legacy-iis.html