# Can ASP.NET Core 5.0.3 Hosting Bundle impact already hosted .Net framework applications

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I have a server with .net framework web applications hosted in IIS.
If I install [ASP.NET Core 5.0.3 Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-5.0.3-windows-hosting-bundle-installer) will it impact already hosted .Net framework applications?

Comment: Yes, it can. You can find tons of 50x crash issues appearing after install the bundle but without VC++ runtime, like this one today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66694615/iis-pool-stops-on-first-request#comment117898435_66694615

Comment: @LexLi Can this brake already hosted .netframework based applications?

Comment: Yes, it can. The linked thread is exactly an example.

Comment: @LexLi but where are the proofs for this? The only link you mention refers to your own comment. This needs more research.

Comment: @SergeyNikitin [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66694615) is just one of issue reports you can find on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Core Hosting bundle is an installer for the .NET Core Runtime and the ASP.NET Core Module. The bundle allows ASP.NET Core apps to run with IIS. According to my test, I found that installing the .NET Core Hosting bundle has no effect on the application of the .net framework.

Comment: Not true. Check the linked post in my comment above, and that's very common a crash issue after installing this bundle.